# Pandas Manipulating merged DFs for aggregation issue

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having trouble normalizing two dataframes into a merged dataframe.  Essentially, I want to end up with a dataframe that has the following columns: `year, country, net_activity_amount`, which is the result of merging two dataframes, one that has `year, donor_country, commitment_amount_usd` and the other which has `year, receiving_country, commitment_amount_usd`.  I am currently getting a dataframe that has the year repeated and some of the countries only exist in one or the other dataframe, which is the reason for the `outerjoin`.

Here is an example row that I currently have: `1977, Saudi Arabia, 3000000, Saudi Arabia, 3000000, 0`

How can I achieve this efficiently?

```
def clean_data():
    raw_data = get_raw_data()

    donor_df = raw_data[['year', 'donor', 'commitment_amount_usd_constant']]

    recip_df = raw_data[['year', 'recipient', 'commitment_amount_usd_constant']]

    merged_df = donor_df.merge(recip_df, how='outer', left_on=["year", "donor"], right_on=["year", "recipient"])

    merged_df = merged_df.fillna(0)

    merged_df['net_donation_activity'] = merged_df.apply(lambda row: calc_net_value(row), axis=1)

    print(merged_df)

def get_raw_data():
    return pd.read_csv('aiddata-countries-only.csv')

def calc_net_value(row):
    # lambda for calculating net diff
    return float(row['commitment_amount_usd_constant_x'] - row['commitment_amount_usd_constant_y'])

def normalize_data(row):
    return []
```

Comment: _I am currently getting a dataframe that has the year repeated and some of the countries only exist in one or the other dataframe, which is the reason for the outerjoin._ Please provide a [mcve], as well as the current and expected output. _I'm having trouble normalizing two dataframes into a merged dataframe._ Since they're both apparently created from the same data source, there might be an easier solution.

Comment: `merged_df['net_donation_activity'] = merged_df.apply(lambda row: calc_net_value(row), axis=1)` can be simplified to `merged_df['net_donation_activity'] = merged_df['commitment_amount_usd_constant_x'] - merged_df['commitment_amount_usd_constant_y']`.